# How to perform operations on groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   ID  A   B   Area
0  1   A1  B1  1.0
1  2   A1  B2  2.0
2  3   A1  B1  0.5
3  4   A1  B2  1.0
4  5   A2  B3  2.0
5  6   A2  B4  6.0
```

What I want to get out is this:

```
   ID  A   B   Area  B as % of A
0  1   A1  B1  1.0   0.333
1  2   A1  B2  2.0   0.666
2  3   A1  B1  0.5   0.333
3  4   A1  B2  1.0   0.666
4  5   A2  B3  2.0   0.25
5  6   A2  B4  6.0   0.75
```

The aim is to add a new column which gives the proportion of the area of each floor A that is accounted for by each room type B (note this is by room type so the value in the output column should be the same for each unique combination of A and B).

So far what I have is:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby(['A','B'])  
>>> area_proportion = lambda x: (x['Area'] / x['Area'].sum())
>>> grouped.transform(area_proportion)
```

But this seems to be treating the lambda as by index of the original dataframe (I thought it would be by group) as it just returns:

```
Out[142]: 
  ID  Area
0  1   1.0
1  2   2.0
2  3   0.5
3  4   1.0
4  5   2.0
5  6   6.0
```

I'm obviously misunderstanding something or missing a vital part of the docs. How should I be using groupby to get the result I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly:

```
>>> aggr = lambda df, key, col: df.groupby(key)[col].transform('sum')
>>> df['B as % of A'] = aggr(df, ('A', 'B'), 'Area') / aggr(df, 'A', 'Area')
>>> df
   ID   A   B  Area  B as % of A
0   1  A1  B1   1.0       0.3333
1   2  A1  B2   2.0       0.6667
2   3  A1  B1   0.5       0.3333
3   4  A1  B2   1.0       0.6667
4   5  A2  B3   2.0       0.2500
5   6  A2  B4   6.0       0.7500
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I was confused by the fact that there are duplicate entries so they should be treated as equivalent rather than separate entries